# Is it possible to do epoll on accept event?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, epoll

Let's suppose I've created a listening socket:

```
sock = socket(...);
bind(sock,...);
listen(sock, ...);
```

Is it possible to do epoll_wait on *sock* to wait for incoming connection? And how do I get client's socket fd after that?

The thing is on the platform I'm writing for sockets cannot be non-blocking, but there is working epoll implementation with timeouts, and I need to accept connection and work with it in a single thread so that it doesn't hang if something goes wrong and connection doesn't come.

Comment: Yes, you need to set the socket to non_blocking mode and should do an accept once you get any read event eg : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729561/asynchronous-c-client-for-a-multiclient-c-server

Comment: Non-blocking is not needed. Just poll for the listening socket to be *readable*.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what this non-standard platform is it's impossible to know exactly what semantics they gave their epoll call. But on the standard epoll on Linux, a listening socket will be reported as "readable" when an incoming connection arrives, and then you can accept the connection by calling `accept`. If you leave the socket in blocking mode, and always check for readability using epoll's level-triggered mode before each call to `accept`, then this *should* work – the only risk is that if you somehow end up calling `accept` when no connection has arrived, then you'll get stuck. For example, this could happen if there are two processes sharing a listening socket, and they both try to `accept` the same connection. Or maybe it could happen if an incoming connection arrives, and then is closed again before you call `accept`. (Pretty sure in this case Linux still lets the `accept` succeed, but this kind of edge case is exactly where I'd be suspicious of a weird platform doing something weird.) You'd want to check these things.

Non-blocking mode is much more reliable because in the worst case, `accept` just reports that there's nothing to accept. But if that's not available, then you might be able to get away with something like this...

Answer (score -1):

Since this answer is the first up in the results in duckduckgo. I will just chime in to say that under GNU/Linux 4.18.0-18-generic (Ubuntu 18.10).

The asynchronously `accept` an incoming connection using one has to watch for `errno` value `EWOULDBLOCK` (11) and then add the socket to epoll **read** set.

Here is a small shot of scheme code that achieves that:

```
(define (accept fd)
  (let ((out (socket:%accept fd 0 0)))
    (if (= out -1)
        (let ((code (socket:errno)))
          (if (= code EWOULDBLOCK)
              (begin
                (abort-to-prompt fd 'read)
                (accept fd))
              (error 'accept (socket:strerror code))))
        out)))
```

In the above `(abort-to-prompt fd 'read)` will pause the coroutine and add `fd` to epoll read set, done as follow:

```
(epoll-ctl epoll EPOLL-CTL-ADD fd (make-epoll-event-in fd)))
```

When the coroutine is unpaused, the code proceed after the abort to call itself recursively (in tail-call position)

In the code I am working in Scheme, it is a bit more involving since I rely on `call/cc` to avoid callbacks. The full code is at [source hut](https://git.sr.ht/~amz3/chez-scheme-arew/tree/1656b24f3044f64a690fc07d44138e9071ff3d01/src/arew/untangle.scm#L16).

That is all.